# Laravel 5.4 @include not working - throws ErrorException View not found

Tags: laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel, using 5.4 in an XAMPP stack and I can't get the @include to work.

Forgive me if I ask some stupid questions here, but this is the first framework I've worked on in nearly two years, so I'm a bit rusty.

I have a view in the resources/views directory, and I just want to include some simple html divs which I would like to be in a separate .inc file.

Basically, I have an index.blade.php view in the resources/views/xxx directory, which works fine, but has divs of html which I'd like to get out of the way in a notes.inc.blade.php file, and then @include it into the index.

I've tried creating the .inc file in the same folder, then using @include('notes.inc') , but this doesn't work. I've also tried moving the inc file to the resources/views directory and then using @include('xxx.notes.inc') but again no joy. All I get is:

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
(2/2) ErrorException
View [notes.inc] not found. 
(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxxxx\resources\views\xxxxxxs\index.blade.php)

I haven't changed any path definitions or configs.

Most of the forums (fora?) that I have found are talking about Laravel 4, so is there anyone that can point me at some clear instructions on how to do it in 5.4?

Or am I missing something obvious?

I would be happy to provide sample code if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view paths are not relative, so if you use `@include('xxx.notes.inc')` in the `resources/views/xxx/index.blade.php`, your included template must be in `resources/views/xxx/notes/inc.blade.php`.

Comment: I meant the view. `If you include @include('xxx.notes.inc')`, the view must be in the path `C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxxxx\resources\views\xxx\notes\inc.blade.php`. Note that Laravel will consider that the dots inside the `include` directive are directory separators.

Comment: Thank you Thiago. Now that I look at it, the answer was pretty obvious.